# Merge polygons from two different layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, mergeshapes

I have a layer with all buildings.
Then I made a layer with buildings of interest from my part.

The problem is that a building of interest is made out of several polygons, but I want it as one polygon.

As in the picture I would like to have the entire building as one polygon.
Is that possible? (I want the whole house in red)

I don't want this made for the entire layer, just the ones I find interesting.

[image]

Comment: Select the buildings of interest in the layer you created. Click the _Edit_ icon (looks like a pencil) and then find the **Merge Selected Features** tool (either from the toolbar or from the `Edit` menu). This will merge your selected features. Or if you want it to _look_ like a single polygon, you could run the **Dissolve** tool :)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
select ST_Union (geom) as geom
From your_name_table
WHERE
id=... or id=...
```

(select id your  sub polygons)